# Is it possible to create virtual subdomains?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a wordpress based site, that has data divided in it on the basis of country and state.

So the url goes like this
http://xyz.com/US/category_id
http://xyz.com/UK/category_id

there are no seperate folders for UK or US. 
I was wondering if it possible to create multiple sub-domains like this

http://US.xyz.com
http://UK.xyz.com

without having different folders to route the sub-domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Of course.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/vhosts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but *how* you implement this depends on the type of service you use.  Most light users purchase a shared hosting service.  Your suppliers FAQs should give you advice.  Some provide a control panel to map individual subdomains to separate subdirectories under your document root.  Others simply map `*.youdomain.com` to your document root.  In this latter case you need to use a `.htaccess` file and decode the `HTTP_HOST` to map each subdomain to a separate directory yourself.

If you do search here for `[.htaccess] HTTP_HOST votes:2` then you will finds lots of examples of how to do this. :-)